# Android studio - plugins

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, plugins

[image]

[image]

*This is my error :*

```
1:04 PM Plugin Error
                Problems found loading plugins:
                Plugin "Android Games" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Android APK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Google Developers Samples" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                Plugin "Test Recorder" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
```

What can i do ?

*Thanks*

Comment: Can post your `build.gradle` files for both top level and module level?

Comment: Shizen, im a begginer in android studio, i dont really know what are you talkin about

Answer (score 1):

I think it is some Android Studio error. I have get it after running some older project. I think it disabled some newer plugins and then get errors. If you deselect and then select again this plugins it seems to help.